# Storing language independent strings in separate yaml files

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

we recently started to develop our website in symfony and are using the twig templating engine. The strings are stored in separate yaml files where we have different files for each language (using them in twig like this `{{ 'variablename' | trans }}`).
Now I wonder what the best way would be to store language independent strings like an email address. We could store them of course in the default language file so all fallback to it, but maybe there is a cleaner way.
Best

Answer (score 1):

Use the default language as key is one way to reach your goal.

Personally I prefer this notation `<bundle>.<section>.<key` (e.g. `acme_user.profile.username`). I'm using this syntax because its more readable and maintainable and symfony (specific YAML) has a build in support for this notation.

```
acme_user:
    profile:
        username: Username
    change_password:
        password: Password
```

In your templates you can access them with `{{ 'acme_user.profile.username'|trans }}`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is already what we are doing. I just thought it would be common to use another global file which is independent of the languages.